# Should I use raw string by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I know raw string, like `r'hello world'`, prevents escaping.

Is it a good practice to always prepend the r symbol even if the string doesn't have any escaping sequences?

Say my exception needs some string literal explanation, I need to connect to a website whose url is a string literal. They don't have backslash. Are there any performance differences between raw string and regular string?

Comment: What if you need a special character? e.g. a newline `'\n'`?

Comment: @wjandrea only then, remove the 'r'

Comment: I would say doing that goes against the intent of the notatian. The `r`, like the `b`, says *notation in this quoted literal is special*. It invites the reader to interpret backslashes differently. If there are none, at least some readers will check and recheck and wonder what they have missed.

Answer (score 3):

The `r` sigil means "backslashes in this string are literal backslashes". Putting this sigil on a string which doesn't contain any backslashes is harmless but sometimes mildly confusing to a human reader. A better approach is probably to only use this sigil when you actually need it.

Situations where the string may not contain backslashes at the moment, but where you might expect to add one in the future, such as in regular expressions and Windows file paths, would probably qualify as useful exceptions.

```
re.findall(r'hello', string)       # what if we switch to r'hello\.'?
with open(r'file.txt') as handle:  # what if we switch to r'sub\file.txt'?
```

It would be easy to forget to add the `r` when you add a backslash, so supplying it in advance has some merit here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Python. But I don't recommend that because if you add something like '\n', it won't work well. You can use that in Regex and paths on Windows.